# Manage layout of docked figures

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm writing a program who will generate a couple of figures and I want to dock them all together. I can, to dock them, use the command:

```
set(fig1,'WindowStyle','docked');
set(fig2,'WindowStyle','docked');
```

etc.

But I can't find how to manage the layout of the figures inside the container or even the container size from the code. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no documented way to programmatically set the docking group of figures.

However, I believe @Yair Altman's `setFigDockGroup`, [available](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16650-setfigdockgroup) from MATLAB Central File Exchange, enables you to do it (by manipulating undocumented properties of the figures and the MATLAB desktop).

Even if it doesn't quite do what you need, I would guess that by looking through that code you would find a way to do it (although you might need to be comfortable with a bit of Java).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have already checked his work, but I didn't found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the `Position` property when figures are docked.

From [Docking Figures in the Desktop](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_plots/docking-figures-in-the-desktop.html):

> If WindowStyle is set to docked,
>
> - MATLAB automatically sets `DockControls` to `on`.
> - You cannot set the `DockControls` property to `off`.
> - *You cannot set the figure* `Position` *property.*

As for laying out the figures, you could use [subplot](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) to display multiple plots in one figure, which you can dock.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but when you're in the figure container with all your docked figures inside, you can adjust the layout (i.e. left/right split, top/bottom split,...) and the size of each figure. Can't you do that from the code?

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented way to achieve this. You can get inspiration from FileExchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46352-editor-session-manager.
This is saving the layout for the Editor Group.
One could adapt for a figure group.